# Structure Reference for Excel Pivot Table Column Labels for Named Range

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm interested in creating a chart for which I can easily change the data source from which the chart is created. However, as I am hoping to grab this data from a pivot table (as I am using a Mac and cannot create pivot charts), I am having some difficulty constructing the named range.

The link below shows what I am hoping to do but with a pivot table rather than a normal table:

http://www.get-digital-help.com/2013/11/06/quickly-change-chart-data-source/#comment-66012

Is this possible? If so, how can I adapt the formulas given in the linked website to use with the pivot table?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want pivot table or like the one in the link shown? If normal table, try what is given in the tutorial.

Comment: I want to adapt the tutorial to use with a pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto Insert --> Pivot Chart
2. Select the data cells along with header. (Apply required formulas to your base data itself)
3. Choose existing or new worksheet as per your requirement.
4. Select the column labels and row labels and sigma values according to your requirement.

Automatically a pivot Bar graph would be generated. This will also have a default filter option where if you select particular values, the graph will automatically get changed.

If there are any modifications to data, just right click the pivot graph and click `refresh Data`.

Comment: I am using the Mac version of Excel. Are the steps the same?

Comment: Am not sure about Mac. But, I think it would be worth giving a try.